# Log2j.xml with specific words

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am not sure if it is possible to only create the message in the log file when the message contains certain text? I am using log4j2.xml and below are all my code.

**1) The UserService class**
package com.example.services;

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {
    Logger confirmLogger = LogManager.getLogger("confirmFile");

    public void log(){
        confirmLogger.warn("printing confirm text with warn");//this should be in the log file
        confirmLogger.info("printing confirm text with info");//this should be in the log file
        confirmLogger.error("printing confirm text with error");//this should be in the log file

        confirmLogger.warn("printing normal text with error");//this should not be inside the log file
    }
}
```

**2) the log4j2.xml**
I wanted the all.log to contains all the logs while confirm.log will only contains the message that has "confirm" word inside the sentence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="allFile"
                 fileName="logs/all.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log"
                 immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="confirmFile"
                 fileName="logs/confirm.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log"
                 immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout>
            <ScriptPatternSelector defaultPattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %l - %msg%n">
                <Script name="LevelSelector" language="bsh"><![CDATA[
                    if (logEvent.getMessage().contains("confirm") ) {
                        return "INFO";
                    }
                    return null;
                    ]]>
                </Script>
                <PatternMatch key="INFO" pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg%n"/>
            </ScriptPatternSelector>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" level="ERROR"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="confirmFile" level="ALL" />
        <AppenderRef ref="allFile" level="ALL" />
    </Root>
</Loggers> </Configuration>
```

Comment: A `PatternSelector` only switches between multiple patterns. Check [filters](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html) instead.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thank you for the advise. I managed to code it. thanks!

Comment: @xxtester: can you publish your modified configuration as an answer (and mark it as accepted)?